# nested if_else statements in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

I'm working with an animal tracking dataset in which I have locations of birds captured across three different states. I'm trying to filter the dataset into the minimum time birds crossed a certain Latitude with the Latitude varying by state. My data looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
BirdsID = c("A", "A", "A", 
             "B", "B", "B", 
             "C","C", "C"),

State = c("AR", "AR", "AR", 
           "LA", "LA", "LA", 
           "TN", "TN", "TN"),

Latitude = c(31, 37, 38, 
              29, 31, 32,
              35, 36, 37),

Time = as.Date(c("2020/04/02", "2020/04/03", "2020/04/04", 
          "2020/04/03", "2020/04/04", "2020/04/05",
          "2020/04/05", "2020/04/06", "2020/04/07")))
```

What I'd like to do is filter the data by Latitude, conditionally upon state. In this case, I'd like to isolate locations of birds from AR above Latitude 36 degrees, LA with Latitude > 30.6, and TN Latitude > 36.5. After filtering, I'd like to distill the data to the minimum time (i.e., the first occasion they were observed above the specified latitude). Here's an attempt which throws an error:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  if_else(State == "AR", true = filter(Latitude > 36),           #If AR, filter >36deg
         if_else(State == "LA", true = filter(Latitude > 30.6),  #If LA, filter >30.6deg
                false = filter(Latitude > 36.5)                  #else, its TN and filter >36.5                  
                       )
                ) %>%
  group_by(BirdsID) %>%                                          #group by bird
  filter(Time == min(Time))                                      #earliest time above filtered Latitude
```

The error I'm receiving for this example is `Error: "condition" must be a logical vector, not a "data.frame" object.` and the error I'm receiving on my actual dataset is `Error: "condition" must be a logical vector, not a "tbl_df/tbl/data.frame" object.`

Any suggestions or assistance w/ nested `ifelse`, `if_else`, or `if()` statements would be appreciated. Best,

Comment: Note that by using `cbind`, you have converted `Latitude` from type numeric to character. I don't know why so many questions here at SO use this cumbersome method of generating data frames, when you could just use the `data.frame()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you want with `group_map` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
# Define a function to apply custom filter by state
custom_filter <- function(data) {
  State <- first(data[["State"]])
  if (State == "AR") {
    result <- data %>% 
      filter(Latitude > 36)
  } else if (State == "LA") {
    result <- data %>% 
      filter(Latitude > 30.6)
  } else {
    result <- data %>% 
      filter(Latitude > 36.5)
  }
  result
}

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  group_map(.f = ~ custom_filter(.x), .keep = TRUE) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  group_by(BirdsID) %>%    
  filter(Time == min(Time))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   BirdsID [3]
  BirdsID State Latitude Time      
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>    <date>    
1 A       AR    37       2020-04-03
2 B       LA    31       2020-04-04
3 C       TN    37       2020-04-07
```

Comment: Thank you both, I like and am saving both answers. I hadn't thought of using `case_when` to index the data. And apologies on `data.frame` generation. I've learned my lesson :) Best, Nick

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::case_when` instead of multiple or nested `ifelse`.

I would use it to flag the data, then filter on the flag. Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(flag = case_when(
    State == "AR" & Latitude > 36 ~ "Y",
    State == "LA" & Latitude > 30.6 ~ "Y",
    State == "TN" & Latitude > 36.5 ~ "Y",
    TRUE ~ "N"
  )) %>% 
filter(flag == "Y") %>% 
group_by(State, BirdsID) %>% 
filter(Time == min(Time))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   State, BirdsID [3]
  BirdsID State Latitude Time       flag 
  <chr>   <chr>    <dbl> <date>     <chr>
1 A       AR          37 2020-04-03 Y    
2 B       LA          31 2020-04-04 Y    
3 C       TN          37 2020-04-07 Y
```

Data - please use `data.frame` !

```
df <- data.frame(BirdsID = c("A", "A", "A", 
                             "B", "B", "B", 
                             "C","C", "C"), 
                 State = c("AR", "AR", "AR", 
                           "LA", "LA", "LA", 
                            "TN", "TN", "TN"),
                 Latitude = Latitude <- c(31, 37, 38, 
                                          29, 31, 32,
                                          35, 36, 37), 
                 Time = as.Date(c("2020/04/02", "2020/04/03", "2020/04/04", 
                                  "2020/04/03", "2020/04/04", "2020/04/05",
                                  "2020/04/05", "2020/04/06", "2020/04/07")))
```

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of nested if_else formula:

```
dat1 <- dat %>%
  mutate (group = ifelse(subject > 2 & subject < 21 | subject == 1 | subject == 22, "patient", "control")) %>%
  mutate (condition = ifelse(stim < 9, "pain", ifelse (stim > 8 & stim < 17, "dep", ifelse(stim > 16 & stim < 25, "pos", "neu"))))
```